# Webview Error Uncaught SecurityError

Tags: android, android-webview

I am getting following error in android webview

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxxxxxxxx.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://xxxxxxxxx.in". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.", source: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/v1/checkout-frame.js (1)

My Webview :

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: what is the url that you are trying to load

Comment: This looks like a [Same-Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) issue which should occur in any browser. If you recognize the behavior described in the link you should consider updating the tags.

Comment: may problem in  the certificate of url

Comment: webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Comment: @SaikrishnaRajaraman does not work

Comment: @sandeep have you solved this issue. struggling with same.

Comment: Does anyone have solved this issue? 'm also facing the same  here.

Comment: @Arush I think I solved this issue by using following
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }

and in manifest file application tab 

<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>

Comment: @sandeepkolhal , Thanks for your response. Yeah, the code shared by you is a part of this solution. Also some websites (Payment Gateways) are using multi site redirecting and pop up in different windows . So we have fixed it by overriding all the methods in this following section. 
                                                                                    
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: @Arush https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068011/razor-pay-failed-inapp-browser-in-android  plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using following

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
```

and in manifest file application tab

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @sandeep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068011/razor-pay-failed-inapp-browser-in-android  plz help me.