# Razor-pay failed Webview in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, razorpay

**Razorpay failed inapp browser in Android**

Razorpay in inapp browser in android app failed before otp screen. but it works fine mobile browser only app inside webview  payment was failed.

Screenshot attached. did anyone face similar bug? looking solutions

[image]

Comment: I got this bug.any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I can't able to comment due to my less reputation in StackOverflow
I have solved this issue by using RazorPay Sdk in android

Comment: Without SDK ,  Webview  any solution ? @Manish

Comment: No, I don't have any solution without SDK

but here let me explain to you how it's working so that can give you some idea

Comment: suppose you are using an app that contains activity and above that activity there is Webview and if you want to implement Razorpay (which is having its own Webview)

so your layout will be like 
Activity ->Webview->Webview(RazorPay)

try to implement this Webview(RazorPay) in new Activity or fragment maybe that will help you to achieve that.